# Why does async waterfall differentiate between multiple callbacks in the function array?

Tags: async.js

```
async.waterfall([
    function(cb) {
      console.log('Inner 1');
      cb(null, '1st');
      cb(null, '1st-Again')
      console.log('After 1');
    },
    function(val, cb) {
      console.log('Inner 2 |' + val);
      cb(null, '2nd');
      cb(null, '2nd-Again');
      console.log('After 2');
    }
], function(err, results) {
  console.log('final cb |' + results);
});
```

The output for the above piece of code is

```
Inner 1
After 1
Inner 2 |1st
After 2
Inner 2 |1st-Again
After 2
final cb |2nd
```

I understand the basic working of waterfall where results get passed to the next function in the array. Could someone kindly explain why I dont see a `final cb | 2nd-Again` printout?  I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction. (I also looked at the source code for waterfall, but could not really make sense of it apart from how once task would automatically call the other).  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are not supposed to call callbacks twice. If you do, you will get very unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You should also look into Promises for async control flow. Everything is just a lot better.

Comment: This code should be erring. I think you're using a pretty dated version of async